# Vue I18n multi language

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

I'm doing multi-language support with vue js, everything works fine, but when I change the language, the data in the data
menuItem name does not change.

[Vuei18n](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/)

```
<template v-slot:MenuItem>
    <MenuItems v-for="(Item,Index) in menuItem"
               :key="Index"
               :items="Item"
               :depth="Index"
    >
        <router-link :to="Item.path">{{Item.name}}</router-link>
    </MenuItems>
</template>

export default {
    name: "Nav",
    data() {
        return {
            menuItem: [
                {
                    name: this.$t('navbar.home'),
                    path: '',
                },
                {
                    name: this.$t('navbar.gallery'),
                    path: 'gallery',
                },
                {
                    name: this.$t('navbar.contact'),
                    path: 'contact',
                },
            ],
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

data() is only called once when **creating** the component, and it's not intended to be reactive.
(So basically when your component is being created, it gets the your current translation as initial values)

To make a property reactive on $t(), you should use computed var instead:

```js
  export default {
    name: "Nav",
    data() {
      // exclude from here
      return {};
    },
    computed: {
      menuItem() {
        return [
          {
            name: this.$t("navbar.home"),
            path: "",
          },
          {
            name: this.$t("navbar.gallery"),
            path: "gallery",
          },
          {
            name: this.$t("navbar.contact"),
            path: "contact",
          },
        ];
      },
    },
  };
```